# Disable some SwiftLint rules for test target/unit tests files

Tags: swift, unit-testing, xctest, swiftlint

I am looking to disable a couple of SwiftLint rules for the unit tests within my application.

For example I am wanting to disable the `weak_delegate` rule for my unit tests.

Having looked at the SwiftLint docs I think it may be possible by defining a custom weak_delegate rule and excluding the path to my unit tests.

https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint#defining-custom-rules

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can disable them at a local level using:

```
//swiftlint:disable weak_delegate
let someDelete: someDelegate?
//swiftlint:enable weak_delegate
```

or at target level, by modifying your .swiftlint.yml file (hidden)

```
weak_delegate:
    excluded: ".*Test\\.swift" //regex path to your tests folder
```

or at project level, by modifying your .swiftlint.yml file (hidden)

```
disabled_rules:
 - weak_delegate
```

Comment: Is not working for me...I will like to disable for unit test but haven't find the way

Answer (score 11):

Best way to exclude some rules for test target is the [nested configuration](https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint#nested-configurations): you add a second .swiftlint.yml to root of your tests directory with rules to disable.

```
disabled_rules:
    - weak_delegate
    - cyclomatic_complexity
    - force_unwrapping
    - function_body_length
```

Comment: Important detail: If you want to use use nested configurations, you can't use the -- config parameter. Check the linked documentation provider by @Barbara K for more info.

Answer (score 6):

Add this to your `.swiftlint.yml`:

```
weak_delegate:
    excluded: ".*Test\\.swift" //regex path to your tests folder
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the script in `Build Phases` to point only to the folder of your source code:

```
if which swiftlint > /dev/null; then
  swiftlint --path "$SRCROOT"/[name_of_source_folder]
else
  echo "warning: SwiftLint not installed, download from https://github.com/realm/SwiftLint"
fi
```

Adding the flag `--path "$SRCROOT"/path_to_folder` will exclude the test targets.