SwiftLint Invalid configuration for 'file_length'. Falling back to default
I configured .swiftlint.yml and have the following error:
warning: Invalid configuration for 'line_length'. Falling back to default.

Here is my configuration:
...
line_length:
  error: 120
  excluded: ".*Tests\\.swift"
...

I found this question https://stackoverflow.com/a/52592513/3992815, which says, that my solution should work.
Any idea?
Thanks

The line_length rule doesn’t have an excluded option. There’s excluded_lines_patterns but that’s not for file names. It allows you to specify a list of patterns which, if they match, cause whole lines to be ignored even if they are “too long”.
To disable the rule for a file, use a // swiftlint:disable command in the file.
